# How to count only new data in pandas, and not the whole table?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

There is a table:

```
import pandas as pd
data = {
    'one': list(range(2, 15, 4)),
    'two': list(range(4, 16, 3))
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df
```

Result:

```
-   one two
0   2   4
1   6   7
2   10  10
3   14  13
```

There is a data processing method:

```
def compute(df):
  df['rol1'] = df.rolling(3, min_periods=1).one.mean()
  df['rol2'] = df.rolling(3, min_periods=1).two.quantile(0.5)
  df['rol3'] = df.rolling(2, min_periods=1).rol2.min()
  return df

df = compute(df)
df
```

The result is:

```
-   one two rol1    rol2    rol3
0   2   4   2.0     4.0     4.0
1   6   7   4.0     5.5     4.0
2   10  10  6.0     7.0     5.5
3   14  13  10.0    10.0    7.0
```

Great, and now a new line is added:

```
newData = {'one': 13, 'two': 6}
df = df.append(newData, ignore_index=True)
df
```

As a result, a line is added, in the remaining fields, NaN is set:

```
-   one     two     rol1    rol2    rol3
0   2.0     4.0     2.0     4.0     4.0
1   6.0     7.0     4.0     5.5     4.0
2   10.0    10.0    6.0     7.0     5.5
3   14.0    13.0    10.0    10.0    7.0
4   13.0    6.0     NaN     NaN     NaN
```

**How now to tell pandas that he would count only the data for the last line?** Because if I call `df = compute(df)` again, it will compute the whole table. And with big data, this is quite a lot of time, but I would like to work with data in real time.
There is an option to create a copy function and use `tail` instead of `rolling`, but I don’t want to make pastes of the same logic. The final algorithm in my program is complicated and I don’t want to duplicate it either.
Thanks in advance for the answer!)

Comment: why dont create a temp df, run compute on it and append that to the original df?

Comment: @najeem  In my case, the temporary DF is too large, because i use a large value in rolling. Optionally calculate only newly added data.

Comment: if your window is large, I think you'll have to write your own logic to calculate your rolling calculations for the newly added row. for eg: `rol1 = ((window_size-1) * last_rol1 + one)/window_size`

Comment: @najeem Yes, I thought about this method. But, as I wrote in the question, I do not want to duplicate logical calculations. But I want to change her.
P.S.:
`rol1 = df.tail(window_size).one.mean()`